# Review of the "general computing hardware and software" rule

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-closed

So I had a question about an IDE called PHPStorm and 5 people flagged it as being off-topic for stackoverflow:

"Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming."

Literally, the only purpose of PHPStorm is for PHP development, how is this considered not "directly involve tools used primarily for programming"?

What else is a programming IDE used for that's not primarily for programming? I don't understand this moderation decision and how 5 separate people can consider a programming IDE not a tool directly related to programming.

---

Question for context [Linux PhpStorm cannot connect to remote server Only SSH2 keys in OpenSSH format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55378678/linux-phpstorm-cannot-connect-to-remote-server-only-ssh2-keys-in-openssh-format)

Answer (score 8):

Questions about IDEs are *fine*.

Your question is in context of using a specific feature of an IDE to actually do something.  The components it involves aren't *exactly* programmer-specific (since not every programmer has to deal with SSH keys), but that doesn't automatically make your question off-topic.

I've rolled back the flame bait in your edit, since it wasn't helping anyone worth anything.  Just be patient on this one; the community got one wrong.

Comment: I'm asking why so many people consider PHPStorm not directly related to a programming tool it makes no sense whatsoever, I can understand 1 or 2 people maybe not knowing what an IDE is but a quick Google would have highlighted this.

Interesting point above, so general questions about 'which IDE should I use?' are mostly okay but questions about IDE's features are generally not?

Comment: Yeah, that's immaterial.  *I* know that PHPStorm is an IDE.  It even has a tag here.  Don't dwell too much on this; honestly, the community got this one wrong.

Comment: okay cool, I thought it was a moderator decision and was totally baffled by the explanation on holding the question. If it's just random people then that makes a little more sense.

Comment: Moderators have diamonds after their display names, like this one. Spoiler alert: sometimes, we make mistakes, too. @twigg

Comment: @CodyGray hey, yeah I understand, mistakes can be made even more so on technically advanced questions. However, this was a basic question which a 5 second Google would show that PHPStorm is a programming IDE, I'm just astonished on a technically minded forum at least 5 people didn't know it was an IDE OR couldn't be bothered to Google it and just decided to take time out of their own day to flag a perfectly legitimate question. The mind boggles